# TabbedPage menu border colour in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When I make a TabbedPage in Xamarin.Forms and launch it on my iPhone 8 simulator in portrait mode, the TabbedPage menu border doesn't show? Is there any way I can set it to a different colour maybe sothat it shows?

[image: No menu border colour]

Thanks, Daniel.

Comment: Set the emulator screen to display 100%, instead of 50% or "fit to screen". Sometimes on the higher resolution emulators, if you have it to "fit to screen" or "50%", you can't see thin lines such as the border for the tab bar. in other words, the border is most likely there, but you simply can't see it due to the current display resolution settings of the emulator.

Comment: @sme Ahh yes, thank you, it worked :)